# Overlapping question

Tags: bug, android-app

I haven't been able to reproduce but I thought I should still report the issue.

After opening the app for the first time, clicking on More options to see current question in the browser, then switching to another question and clicking on Read this on our app then, finally, clicking on feed and loading a Hot question, resulted in having the two last questions loaded at the same time, overlapping.

Really weird looking especially when try to scroll up and down. I closed the app and tried to reproduce, unsuccessfully.

I'm using a Samsung Galaxy Tab 3.